# numpy fancy indexing axis order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a problem using numpy fancy indexing which I somehow can't get my head around.
I know, that I can get an array of submatrices of rows like this:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
B = A[np.array([[0,1],[1,2]])]
```

This gives:

```
array([[[1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6]],

   [[4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]]])
```

a threedimensional numpy array containing matrices comprising the first,second row and second,third row of A, respectively.
What I want is now basically the same operation for the cols of A which should give

```
array([[[1, 2],
      [4, 5],
      [7, 8]],

      [[2, 3],
      [5, 6],
      [8, 9]]])
```

But

```
B = A[:,np.array([[0,1],[1,2]])]
```

does not work (probably because of the order of the index evaluations). It gives

```
array([[[1, 2],
    [2, 3]],

   [[4, 5],
    [5, 6]],

   [[7, 8],
    [8, 9]]])
```

How can I accomplish this in the best way? Should I work with transposed matrices?

Comment: What is "numpy fancy indexing"?

Comment: Im not sure if this is a common denomination. But I mean to say, that you index a numpy array by another array. In the numpy documentation they call this "advanced indexing" I think

Comment: Show the wrong `B`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a (3,2,2) array:

```
In [417]: B
Out[417]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [2, 3]],

       [[4, 5],
        [5, 6]],

       [[7, 8],
        [8, 9]]])
```

The 3 is from the first axis of A.  The (2,2) from `B`.

Swap the first 2 axes:

```
In [418]: B.transpose(1,0,2)
Out[418]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [4, 5],
        [7, 8]],

       [[2, 3],
        [5, 6],
        [8, 9]]])
```

A (2,3,2) array

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
B = A[np.array([[0,1,2],[0,1,2]])]
C = [list(), list()]
for i in range(2):
    for j in  range(3):
        C[i].append(list(B[i][j][:2]) if i==0 else list(B[i][j][1:3])) 
        
C = np.array(C)
C
```

output:

```
array([[[1, 2],
        [4, 5],
        [7, 8]],

       [[2, 3],
        [5, 6],
        [8, 9]]])
```

Comment: Well...  while this seems like an elegant solution =) Im looking for something vectorized without for loops. Also it is enough for me to go A -> C

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to create `B` from `A.T` and then [swapaxes](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.swapaxes.html):

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])

B = A.T[np.array([[0,1],[1,2]])] 

C = B.swapaxes(-2,-1)
```

To check intermediate step and result:

```py
B
array([[[1, 4, 7],
        [2, 5, 8]],

       [[2, 5, 8],
        [3, 6, 9]]])

C 
array([[[1, 2],
        [4, 5],
        [7, 8]],

       [[2, 3],
        [5, 6],
        [8, 9]]])
```